# DAX: Max Concurrent Events of the same type in Slicer Defined Interval

Tags: dax

I have been working on a measure for way too many hours to calculate the max count of events within a slicer defined interval.

I've tried things similar to this [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Counting-concurrent-calls/m-p/186560) but the query takes way too long(working with 10,000,000 rows of data) and then fails.
I'm trying to write it as a measure to use within a visualization and work with a dynamic slicer, but also not have to use the power query editor.

I'm not even sure if this will be possible within PowerBI with Dax, but was hoping to figure something out.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Data Example:

```
| eventID | eventTypeID | startTime            | endTime              |
|---------|-------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| a1      |  fishing    | 12 jan 2020 12:00:01 | 12 jan 2020 12:30:47 |
| a2      |  eating     | 12 jan 2020 01:00:01 | 12 jan 2020 02:01:32 |
| a3      |  fishing    | 12 jan 2020 12:20:01 | 12 jan 2020 02:11:55 |
| a4      |  talking    | 12 jan 2020 03:00:01 | 12 jan 2020 04:30:59 |
| a5      |  run        | 12 jan 2020 12:00:01 | 12 jan 2020 12:35:01 |
| a6      |  fishing    | 12 jan 2020 12:10:01 | 12 jan 2020 02:10:15 |
```

I'm trying to find:

```
| eventTypeID | maxConcurrent |
|-------------|---------------|
| fishing     | ##            |
| eating      | ##            |
| run         | ##            |
| talking     | ##            |
```

SOLUTION:

I ended up creating a calculated table with the following code:

```
Expanded_EventTable = 
GENERATE(
    FILTER(myTable,myTable[EndTime]>=DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1,MONTH(NOW()), DAY(NOW()-1))),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        GENERATESERIES(
            myTable[StartTime],
            myTable[EndTime],
            TIME(0,1,0)
        ),
        "Expanded_Events", (MROUND([Value], TIME(0,1,0)) + TIME(0,0,0))
    )
)
```

This has been helpful for visualizations but I'm still struggling with calculating the correct max value.

Comment: What do you mean by concurrent (I haven't used that word enough)? and can you please confirm the numbers that want to show against each eventTypeID based on the sample data?

Comment: @AntrikshSharma by concurrent, I mean overlapping time intervals.

Comment: @AntrikshSharma For the sample data the numbers should be
fishing: 3, Eating: 0, Talking: 0, Run: 0